# BUG: Number of Projects Displayed on Main Projects page is Incorrect

Tags: sonarqube

We are having an issue with our SonarQube installation where it always reports that there are two additional projects more than we have data available to review. This shows up on the Projects page at the very bottom where the count appears as "51 of 53 shown" yet clicking the "Show More" link does nothing.

Looking in the Administration / Projects page - SonarQube says that there are only 51 projects in the database. It would appear that the SQL query which calculates the number of projects on the main projects page is different (and incorrect) versus the SQL query that is used on the Administration / Projects page.

Could this be caused by some bad data in the database? If this is the case, any suggestions on how to find and delete the data that is causing this issue?

Comment: Please try stopping the server, deleting _$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es_ and restarting.

Comment: Always mention the SonarQube version you use.

Comment: I am using SonarQube version 6.5 (build 27846). And your recommendation of deleting $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es solved our issue.

Thank you for your help on this!